# Is it possible to make two files with the same size and the same MD5 and CRC32?

Tags: collision-resistance, md5, crc

I have seen a lot of different files with the same MD5s. For CRC32 is quite easy to find collision. But is is it possible to make size, and two different hashes the same?

I have seen many linux packages has only one SHA test-sum, why not to increase security with another hashing function?

(I am not asking about SHA family - answer is YES, possible, but MUCH MORE UNREALISTIC)

Comment: All known methods for producing MD5 and SHA1 collisions faster than brute force will produce a collision of two inputs of identical length. So including the size provides zero additional security.

Comment: In the same paper (see below) Joux also finds that using two different hashes is not more secure than using a single hash.

Comment: @OrangeDog Yes, now I understand that is better to use more difficult hashing function than many less-collision stable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Is it possible to make two files with the same size and the same MD5 and CRC32?

It's straight-forward.

First off, we start with [Joux's multicollision attack (PDF)](https://www.iacr.org/archive/crypto2004/31520306/multicollisions.pdf) to generate $2^{33}$ different same-sized files with the same MD5.  Here's how that works; the MD5 collision attack works by starting with an internal MD5 state $S$, and finding two different blocks $B_0, B_1$ such that, with the MD5 compression function, $\text{MD5Compress}( S, B_0 ) = \text{MD5Compress}( S, B_1 )$.  Finding such a $B_0, B_1$ is fairly easy.

What Joux's attack is ask us to do that 33 times to succesive states; and so we have $2^{33}$ different sequences (as there are $2^{33}$ different ways of selecting $B_0, B_1$ values) that all hash to the same final value.

Once we have that, we know that there exists a pair of files with the same CRC32 value (and actually, we don't need to search through them all, with CRC32, we can find such a pair with linear algebra)

Comment: Could you improve your question by explaining how are the files found with linear algebra?